# Blade Comments in Laravel are crashing apache

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

any comments included in a blade are causing apache to crash when I try to load said page. The project I'm working on uses blade comments for notes and everything, so removing them isn't an option. I'm using xampp on windows.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: personally, i usually comment it like
@if(1==0)
comment here
@endif
i know it's silly, lol.

Comment: I have the same thing happening, only for unclosed or badly formed comments.

`{{-- blah blah --}}` is fine, `{{-- blah blah --    }}` is not

Comment: personally i don't like blade or any other template engine. It's just some extra work for the server to process.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830200/laravel-blade-comments-blade-rendering-causing-page-to-crash

Comment: @kibibu is correct: If you have a malformed Blade comment, no code will be parsed until the next <?php tag. This can cause various errors. Additionally, having blade code inside of blade comments can lead to more parsing problems. I've answered the question linked to by astro in relation to this issue.

Comment: @TonyArra it's not correct. It crashes *Apache*, which requires a hard restart.

Comment: @kibibu even just single-line comments?

Comment: Try using {!-- comment --!}, or possibly {{{ comment }}}. I had a problem similar to this a while back. I don't remember the details but this was the solution I found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Blade comments , blade rendering causing page to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830200/laravel-blade-comments-blade-rendering-causing-page-to-crash)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must ensure that your blade opening and closing tags are correct and don't use the `@` character in the comment:

```
{-- Should work --}

{-- @will crash --}

{--

that @doesn't work either

--}
```

Comment: This was it. I was commenting out some blade stuff with the @sign, and it stopped crashing when they were removed. Thank you!