# Laravel shows blank page (continuously loading)

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

After having installed Laravel 5.1 on a local desktop, I installed it on a webserver (debian 8, php 5.6.17), set the directory permissions for storage and bootstrap/cache tp 1777. All worked fine. Next I installed it on another webserver, same method, same settings, but now it only shows a coninuously loading page. Tried a re-install, with the same result

Started manual debugging and the code falters in the index.php at $kernel->terminate(.... I also changed caching and session storage to redis, which made no difference.

Have been reading through the 'blank pages' posts, and been googling on it too, without any helpfull result so far.

If I let the script die before the '$kernel->terminate(...' line it shows the page else it just shows the page loading ... Unfortunately, pagination, and sorting a.o. do not work due to the premature ending of the script.

Anyone encountered this peculiar behaviour before

Cheers,

Comment: [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen)

Comment: Did you change permission in public folder and storage folder to writable?

Comment: Yes, storage and sub dirs are currently 777 and bootstrap/cache dito. Did that on installation

Comment: Probably permission issue. try setting right permission. example  `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/storage` and sudo `chown -R :www-data /var/www/laravel`

Comment: check your php version installed in server

Answer (score 1):

It happens most probably due to permission issue.Try this

```
chmod 777 -R storage/
```

Storage folder existed inside the Laravel folder.If nothing works, try to give full permission to Laravel Project folder and try again.

Comment: see my response to  John Roca above, I even set the sticky bit to 1 chmod -Rv 1777 ./storage and checked the result with the verbose (v) option

Answer (score 0):

Problem caused by NFS filesystem. It doesn't allow file locking. Solved the problem by writing sessions to memcached

Answer (score 0):

For me what fixed my issue was removing some laravel comment in my blade files. Especially comments of html code on multiple lines.
It took afew days to figure it out!! Very annoying.
{{-- 
html code here
--}}

see:
[Blade Comments in Laravel are crashing apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174162/blade-comments-in-laravel-are-crashing-apache)
[Laravel - Blade comments , blade rendering causing page to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830200/laravel-blade-comments-blade-rendering-causing-page-to-crash)