# Lravel 5.0 - (This site can’t be reached The connection was reset)

Tags: laravel-5

I receive the following error message in "some" of my laravel webpages project:

This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Any advise please

Comment: [You should have ask Google at first.](https://www.google.com/search?q=ERR_CONNECTION_RESET&oq=ERR_CONNECTION_RESET&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: thanks for your replay. actually i already googled it, but i could not find a fix for my problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the problem is because of the commenting syntax i am using. for example:

```
{{--
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
   </button>
</div>
--}}
```

Comment: You're righ Yasky; same is here. but that was the problem.
not only for me, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830200/laravel-blade-comments-blade-rendering-causing-page-to-crash