# Comment in .blade.php template

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I am new in blade template. How i comment here?

PHP i can comment like this

```
<?php // echo $games;?>
```

Laravel Blade

> {{ $game }}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Blade comments , blade rendering causing page to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830200/laravel-blade-comments-blade-rendering-causing-page-to-crash)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In blade syntax, a comment starts with `{{--` and ends with `--}}`

```
{{-- this is a comment --}}
```

But to comment out multiple lines, use standard **PHP block comments** instead, like:

```php
<?php /* 
@if ($condition)
    {{ HTML::form("foo") }};
@endif
*/ ?>
```

**And never nest Blade and/or PHP code** inside of Blade comments.

> **See also** stackoverflow.com/[Why Blade comment causes page to crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28243603/8740349)

Comment: Do what u say: {{ --$games-- }}

Comment: display that error: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_projects\query_builder\resources\views\games.blade.php)

Comment: Please make sure that you have `{{--` _without_ spaces between `{{` and `--`, then you may place your comment content, for example : `{{-- $games --}}`

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as Accepted to resolve this question.